# Unable to open database "test.sql": unable to open database file in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I'm new to objective c. I'm trying to create database for first time in my mac i did following steps

```
******100$ sqlite3 test.sql
SQLite version 3.7.5
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
```

But wen i enter .schema I'm getting following error

```
sqlite> .schema
Error: unable to open database "test.sql": unable to open database file
```

And same error if i go to create a teble

Comment: I am beginning to suspect that you have a text file called `test.sql` and you are attempting to open it as a database using the `sqlite3` command line tool...

Comment: ya i got it thanx a lot  trojanfoe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Firefox addon SQLite Manager to create database.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$ sqlite3 test.sql
SQLite version 3.6.20
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test (a_int INTEGER, a_real REAL, a_text TEXT);
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE test (a_int INTEGER, a_real REAL, a_text TEXT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO test (a_int, a_real, a_text) VALUES (1, 1.24, 'hello world');
sqlite> SELECT * from test;
1|1.24|hello world
sqlite>
```

(this was from Linux, but it should be the same...)

BTW the file extension `.sql` is wrong; that is used for a file containing SQL statements.  Use `.db` instead.

Comment: thanks trojanfoe   but the error is same even after trying what you've given above

Comment: @MudduPatil Are you working in a directory that you have write access?

Comment: @MudduPatil And the `test.sql` file doesn't exist?  (as I said in my answer, `.sql` is used for a different thing than a database file).

Answer (score 0):

Check this link for Create database, create table  insert into table .

[Creating an SQLite3 database file through Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540728/creating-an-sqlite3-database-file-through-objective-c/11795399#11795399)