# C++ And SQLite - How to execute a query formed by user input?

Tags: c++, string, sqlite, char

I'm working on a project where the user can insert a record into a SQLite database.
The query will come generated automatically in the following method:

```
string ID = "";
string title = "";
string password = "";

cout << "Insert ID:\n";
cin >> ID;
cout << "Insert title of password:\n";
cin >> title;
cout << "Insert password:\n";
cin >> password;

string sql = "INSERT INTO test (ID,title,password) VALUES(" + ID + "," + title + "," + password + ");";
```

When i try to compile the program i get the error:

```
    classes.h:74:76: error: invalid operands of types ‘const char*’ and ‘const char [2]’ to binary ‘operator+’
   string sql = "INSERT INTO passwords (ID,title,password) VALUES (" + id + "," + title + "," + password 
                                                                            ^
classes.h:78:42: error: invalid operands of types ‘int’ and ‘sqlite3_stmt*’ to binary ‘operator&’
    sqlite3_prepare( db, sql.c_str(), -1 &st, NULL);
```

seem that he can't accept multiple character.
Can someone show me how to fix this error?

P.S. I'm new in c++

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:

FULL CODE

```
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_stmt * st;
int id = 0;
string title = "";
string password = "";

cout << "Insert ID:\n";
        cin >> id;
        cout << "Insert title of password:\n";
        cin >> title;
        cout << "Insert password:\n";
        cin >> password;

        string sql = "INSERT INTO passwords (ID,title,password) VALUES (" + id + ',' + title + ',' + password + ");";

        if(sqlite3_open("pw.db", &db) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            sqlite3_prepare( db, sql.c_str(), -1 &st, NULL);
            sqlite3_step( st );
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Failed to connect\n";
        }
sqlite3_finalize(st);
sqlite3_close(db);
```

Comment: Never, ever, use raw user input to form a sql query, unless your purpose is to show why it is a bad idea.  I don't care if it is some toy project.

Comment: Yes,it is a project for personal use.

Comment: `std::to_string(id)` (assuming the last smatter of code in this post is the *actual* problem, where `id` is indeed declared as `int`).

Comment: You should avoid directly putting user input into the SQL statement like this, that's how SQL injections happen. Consider using sqlite3_bind_*... See http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/sqlite/bind_insert.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should avoid directly inserting user input into your SQL commands like this, a user could enter malicious text that deliberately alters the resulting SQL statement.

Instead, consider using parameter binding, this will allow you to avoid the string concatenation you're attempting to do. Your code:

```
    string sql = "INSERT INTO passwords (ID,title,password) VALUES (" + id + ',' + title + ',' + password + ");";

    if(sqlite3_open("pw.db", &db) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_prepare( db, sql.c_str(), -1 &st, NULL);
        sqlite3_step( st );
    }
```

becomes

```
    string sql = "INSERT INTO passwords (ID,title,password) VALUES (?,?,?)";

    if(sqlite3_open("pw.db", &db) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_prepare( db, sql.c_str(), -1 &st, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_int(st, 1, ID);
        sqlite3_bind_text(st, 2, title.c_str(), title.length(), SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(st, 3, password.c_str(), password.length(), SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_step( st );
    }
```

the `1`, `2` and `3` are 1-based parameter indexes. See https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html

Answer (score -1):

Your error message shows that the ID is declared as int in the database, but it gets a string from your c++ code. Change this line: string ID = "";   to this: int ID;

Comment: The id is declared as a integer...anyway I added the full code

Comment: Also check the quotes in the statement. string sql = "INSERT INTO passwords (ID,title,password) VALUES ('" + id + "','" + title + "','" + password + "');";

Comment: Just found something useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945980/sqlite-insert-statement-with-c