# SQLite add or insert value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

I have a table with values. I need to add or insert value in it. For example in table exists row("exml") with value: "123", and I want to add value "4567". After that it must be "1234567", if value does not exist it must be "4567", please help me..

Comment: will you edit your question with more detail like table structure and example in format of tabular form.

Comment: See the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html), particularly the links on SQL syntax and C/C++ API.

Answer (score 0):

For This you have to first get existing data from table and then put a loop for Number of Records you got in database,
Then you can do like this,

```
    for(int i=0;i<arrOldData.count;i++)
    {
        NSString *strNew;
        if([[arrOldData objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"exml"])
        {
            strNew=[[[arrOldData objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"exml"] stringByAppendingString:yourNewString];
        }
        else
        {
            strNew=yourNewString;
        }

        //your insert statement will be here with value(strNew)
    }
```

this is not complete code,this will just give you a brief idea of what you can do,
I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

> Check the link it is described  Creating Database, Creating Table ,
>
> Open Database  Retrieve data From the table
>
> It  will help you for inserting  and retrieving values.

[Creating an SQLite3 database file through Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540728/creating-an-sqlite3-database-file-through-objective-c/11795399#11795399)

Checkthis.